# Split file into good and bad data

Tags: awk

I have a file `file1.txt` the data is like below

```
HDR|2016-10-24
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME|DNIS_CODE|1
DTL|10000|SRC_ORD_ID|SRC_ORD_TYPE_CD|SRC_ORD_STAT_CD|SRC_ACCT_ID|SRC_DISC_RSN_CD|1858-11-17|1858-11-18|1858-11-19|1858-11-20|1858-11-21|1858-11-22|ORD_STATUS_CD|ORDER_CREA_USER_ID|REGION_NM|STATE_CD|ORDER_TYPE|BILL_NAME|FEED_TYPE_CD|101|CREA_APPLN_NAME|BILL_TELE_NUM|CUST_CD|DIGITAL_LIFE_FLAG|CUSTOMER_TYPE_CD|VENDOR_NAME|SITE_NAME
TRL|11
```

Now I want to create two set of files good and bad. Good should be where all 29 separators are there. Where it is less than or more than 29 separator (which is pipe) it should go into bad file.

```
IN_FILE=$1
FNAME=`echo $IN_FILE | cut -d"." -f1 | awk '{$1 = substr($1, 1, 26)} 1'`
DFNAME=$FNAME"_Data.txt"
DGFNAME=$FNAME"_Good.txt"
DBFNAME=$FNAME"_Bad.txt"
TFNAME=$FNAME"_Trl.txt" 

cat $IN_FILE | awk -v DGFNM="$DGFNAME" -v DBFNM="$DBFNAME" '
{ {FS="|"}
    split($0, chars, "|")
    if(chars[1]=="DTL")
    {  
       NSEP=`awk -F\| '{print NF}'`
        if [ "$NSEP" = "29" ]
        then
           print substr($0,5) >> DGFNM
        else
           print $0 >> DBFNM
        fi
    }
}'
```

But I am getting some error on this.

```
awk: cmd. line:5:    NSEP=`awk -F\| {print
awk: cmd. line:5:         ^ invalid char '`' in expression
```

Comment: way too much code. how about `awk '-F|' 'NF==29{print $0 > "/path/to/goodfile" ; next} NF!=29{print $0 > "/path/to/badfile"} inFile` (or similar). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
awk -F'|' -v DGFNM="$DGFNAME" -v DBFNM="$DBFNAME" '
  $1 == "DTL" {
    if (NF == 29) {
      print substr($0, 5) > DGFNM
    } else {
      print > DBFNM
    }
  } 
' "$IN_FILE"
```

Your code has two main problems:

- it uses shell syntax (such as `` `....` `` and `[ ... ]`) inside an `awk` script, which is not supported.
- it performs operations explicitly that `awk` performs implicitly by default.

Also:

- it is best to avoid all-uppercase variable names - both in the shell and in `awk` scripts - because they can conflict with reserved variables.
- As @tripleee points out in a comment, you can pass filenames directly to Awk (as in the above code) - no need for `cat` and a pipelin.

Comment: `-F\|`should be enough.

Comment: Oh and don't forget the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @JamesBrown: Good point - you can get away with sending a mere `|` to `awk`, although the conceptually clearest form is `'\\|'`, given that the value is interpreted as a _regex_. (The original form I used, `'\|'`, actually generates a warning in _GNU_ `awk`.)

Answer (score 1):

In essence:

```
$ awk -F\| 'NF==30 {print > "good.txt"; next}{print > "bad.txt"}' file1.txt
```

29 separators means 30 fields, just check the `NF`.